# Parse Error at Socket.socketOnData

Tags: node.js, sockets, http, httprequest, serversocket

what's this error and how do I solve it?

```
Error: Parse Error
at Socket.socketOnData (http.js:1583:20)
at TCP.onread (net.js:525:27)
```

I'm trying to simulate an attack on a server, so my program is sending lot's of http-requests. I guess the problem is something with the limits on the sockets or on the servers...

I changed the ulimit to 6000:

> ulimit -n 6000

but didn't help much...

Answer (score 2):

In my case the header's "content-length" property was insufficient for the data being posted.
Make sure "content-length" is set to the length of the data you are sending.

Comment: I had that too, forgot about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with the POST request handling:

```
request.on('data', function (data) {
    body +=data;
}); 
request.on('end',function(){
    ... //do some stuff
    }       

    var headers={'Content-Type': 'text/plain'};
    response.writeHeader(200, headers); 
    response.end();
});
```

transferring my code to GET method solved it.

now I can send a response immediately and then process the queryData from GET.

I still not completely understand why and how this solved it... but "if it works - don't touch it!" :)